# How to keep raising the dragging event until mouse up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, drag

The following code snippet work only when my mouse is dragging/moving. 
I want to keep raising drag event until I mouse up.

In short I want to raise mouse drag event once I start mouse-down/move and stop once I mouse up.

```
var scaleLeft = document.createElement('div');
scaleLeft.className = "scaleLeft";
jQuery(scaleLeft).draggable({``
    containment: "#plLstOuterWp",
    axis: "x",
    scroll: false,
    cursor: 'ew-resize',
    drag: function (e) {
         _MyFunction(this);
    } 
});

function _MyFunction(event)
{
 console.log(event.style.left);
}
```

Thanks
Chirag.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct!

Check if there are any issues with the page elements and selectors.

Working Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnuco431/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='box'>box</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
    position : absolute;
    border : 1px solid red;
    background-color : pink;
    text-align : center;
    padding : 20px 50px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#box').draggable({
        axis: "x",
        scroll: false,
        cursor: 'ew-resize',
        drag: function (e) {
             _MyFunction(this);
        } 
    });
});

function _MyFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.style.left);
}
```